# Unable to run RSPec using RubyMine. RSpec running fine with ubuntu terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rspec, rubymine

I am facing issue with running RSpec using RubyMine. I am getting the following error whenever I attempt to run test with RubyMine. But if I use normal Ubuntu terminal, things all working fine.

Do anyone know why I am getting this error? If there is any gem issue or any path issue, then I should not be able to run it via terminal also right?

```
/bin/bash -c "/home/meowcat/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.6.6 do /home/meowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby /home/meowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/rspec /home/meowcat/project/myProject/spec/api/v1/api_controller_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format 'Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter' --example ApiController"
Testing started at 2:27 AM ...
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /home/meowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin is not at first place.
         <log>Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for <code>PATH=...</code> entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: <code>rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles</code>
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: <code>rvm use ruby-2.6.6</code>
         To ignore this error add <code>rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1</code> to your <code>~/.rvmrc</code> file.

An error occurred while loading spec_helper. - Did you mean?
                    rspec ./spec/spec_helper.rb

Failure/Error: require 'mongoid-rspec'

Gem::ConflictError:
  Unable to activate mongoid-5.4.1, because activemodel-5.0.7.2 conflicts with activemodel (~> 4.0)
# /home/meowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
# /home/meowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
# /home/meowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# LoadError:
#   cannot load such file -- mongoid-rspec
#   /home/meowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
Run options: include {:full_description=>/ApiController/}

All examples were filtered out
```

My Conf:
[image]

[image]

Comment: that might be related to a similar issue on the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25745 The problem is that it's hard to reproduce it. If you can leave there a comment describing your setup and sharing if possible a project sample that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it invoked the `rspec` command directly without using `bundle exec` and hence the gem dependency wasn't handled correctly.

You can try enable running your rspec in Rubymine with bundler context enabled so that the gems can be loaded correctly. See attached image for the configuration.

[Rubymine Rspec config screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZgOh.png)

Comment: @CrazyCat can you screenshot your Rubymine rspec config and post it here?

Comment: @lee I have added the screenshots.... I had darked out some project name and username. Consider is as /home/meowcat/project/myProject